# Program cannot read module-info and packages properly in JavaFX

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I am creating simple programs in JavaFX in Java 11 (Intellij Idea). Several days ago i had new update (of Intellij Idea), which complicated everything. I haven't been able to run any program, which were using javaFX, everything ended with that screen: [image: Crash after update] I couldn't repair this bug, so I decided to reinstall Intellij and my JDK. Now I have java 11 and for while everything was okay, till first change. It ended with this crash, which I cannot repair also:

```
Information:java: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.4, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:349)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scan(ModulePath.java:236)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(ModulePath.java:189)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.findAll(ModulePath.java:165)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findAll(Resolver.java:842)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.bind(Resolver.java:223)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:482)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:288)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getServiceLoader(JavacFileManager.java:985)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain$2.invoke(JavacMain.java:290)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorLoader(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:261)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:237)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:193)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1136)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:195)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:460)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:330)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:255)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:213)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1324)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1004)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1071)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:965)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:794)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Information:java: Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package mainPackage not found in module
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleInfo.invalidModuleDescriptor(ModuleInfo.java:1092)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleInfo.doRead(ModuleInfo.java:325)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModuleInfo.read(ModuleInfo.java:132)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readExplodedModule(ModulePath.java:688)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:319)
Information:java:   ... 48 more
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'Kalkulator'
Information:javac 11.0.4 was used to compile java sources
Information:06.08.2019 13:51 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2 s 812 ms
Error:java: java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: D:\Java\JavaProjekty\Kalkulator\target\classes
```

. It disappear when I rebuild project but after any change it occurs again. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is it a Maven-based project? Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: It is maven project, but earlier everything was okey (before update).

Comment: Could you build it using maven goal?